# Sudden "Failed to load hostfxr.dll"

Tags: c#

I'm working in a solution that has several .net core (as well as standard and framework) projects.

Up until this morning, when I debugged a .net core project it would launch fine. This morning, that broke. I get an error stating

> The library hostfxr.dll was found , but loading it from XXX failed

- When I build the project, and try running the EXE, the same thing
  happens.
- When I add a new project to the solution, it works fine.
- When running the built debug version on another machine (with the
  .net core SDKs), I get the same issue
- When I change the project to
  run in Release, it works fine.
- When I change the project to run in Debug, and 32bit, it works fine
- When I build the project via cli/dotnet build -c Debug, it works.
- When I build the project via Visual Studio, in Debug, in 32bit it works.
- When I build the project via Visual Studio, in Debug, in 64bit it doesn't work.
- I've cleaned/rebuild the project.
- I've restarted
- I've updated my Visual Studio
- I've removed and reinstalled the .net core SDK

Any suggestions on what happened and how I can fix it?

Im running Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019

UPDATE
After performing my Windows updates overnight, it no longer works when I use dotnet build.

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/4240

Comment: @stuartd, thanks, but that fix is for windows 7, updated my post to mention 10.

Comment: ?? first comment on the issue is: _"We're seeing the same issue on Windows 10 1903"_

Comment: Correct, but there is no solution for windows 10. The solution is to install the KB for windows 7

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry for the distraction.

Comment: @stuartd, no worries. Your article lead me to notice some more scenarios where it does/doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that a clean/rebuild doesnt completely clean the solution.

After I deleted the obj and bin folders, and restarted VS, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In our case (with a build server on Windows Server 2019), it was a case of user rights.

The user that executed the build process (Jenkins), did have access to the folder where hostfxr.dll was located, but required to be an administrator on the build server.

Test the process running under the name of an admin, before re-installing frameworks or installing any Windows Updates.